# How to trigger selectionChange event for already selected item in sap.m.combobox?

Tags: sapui5

I know that the selectionChange event won't trigger again for already selected items. Is there any way to trigger on an already selected item?

Basically, when the selectionChange event occurs in the combobox, the bottom item is highlighted, and the item name is completed in advance in the input field.

For example, when I type A, BCD appears to be pre-completed. If selectionChange can't be triggered only for already selected items, can't we know the pre-completed text when the default browser input event is triggered?

Comment: would you mind clarifying your question. Are you simply asking for the selectionChange event to be triggered once you drop down the comboBox and select the same item already selected?

Answer (score 0):

Try fireSelectionChange()
In your SelectionChange method you will get combo box in mParameters and oSource through which you get current selected key/value if your combo box.